Converge Rate of Iterative Method
Given $f(x)\in C^2[a,b]$ s.t there is a point $x_0$ s.t $f(x_0)=0,f'(x_0)\ne 0 $, and the iterative method is defined as follows : $$ x_{k+1} = x_k - 2f(x_k)/[f(x_k)+2f'(x_k)] $$ I'd like to have some help with finding the convergence rate of the method above. I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the solution, thanks in advance. I was trying to apply Taylor expansion on $f(x_k)$
but no luck so far!
PS: I'm a new user so I had to rely on previous questions for proper format.

At a guess, assuming that $x_k \to x_0$, I would imagine that it behaves like a Newton iteration since $f(x_0) = 0$.

At the end of the day, this is still a fixed-point iteration scheme, with a new iteration function given as $$ g(x) = x-\frac{2f(x)}{f(x)+2f'(x)}. $$ The convergence of a fixed point iteration scheme is controlled by the derivative of the iteration function at the fixed point, so we need to compute $g'(x_0)$. We can proceed directly to get $$ g'(x) = 1-\frac{2f'(x)(f(x)+2f'(x))-2f(x)(f'(x)+2f''(x))}{(f(x)+2f'(x))^2} = 1-\frac{4f'(x)^2-4f(x)f''(x)}{(f(x)+2f'(x))^2}$$ And since $f(x_0)=0$ this means $$g'(x_0) = 1 - \frac{4f'(x_0)^2}{4f'(x_0)^2} = 0. $$
So this means that the scheme converges at least quadratically. To verify that it does not converge cubically, a prioi, one would need to take $g''(x_0)$ and verify that it is not $0$, and $g''(0)$ will actually determine the convergence rate then since $$g(x_0+\epsilon)= g(x_0) + g'(x_0)\epsilon + \frac{1}{2}g''(x_0) \epsilon^2 + \dots \\ = x_0 + \frac{1}{2}g''(x_0)\epsilon^2+\dots \approx x_0 + \frac{1}{2}g''(x_0)\epsilon^2$$ means that $$ g(x_n)-x_0 \approx \frac{1}{2}g''(x_0)(x_n-x_0)^2 $$ so this second derivative determines the constant associated with the quadratic convergence of the method.

Thank you for the insight and the quick reply!

This is the standard Newton method for the function
$$
g(x)=e^{x/2}f(x),
$$
which obviously has the same roots as $f$.
Thus it inherits all the properties of the Newton method.
In polynomial (and other) root-finding, sometimes a complex factor in the exponent, like $g(x)=e^{i\epsilon x}f(x)$, is used to get away from the real axis to find the complex roots.

Thank you. I haven't thought of such approach
